# Unable to access Flask app in local network

Tags: flask, lan

I want to access the flask app from a different device within the same local network. I ran the flask app using:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='5000')
```

And tried accessing the flask app through my other device using:

```
192.168.18.10:5000
```

with 192.168.18.10 being the ipv4 of the device I'm running my application on. I have tried allowing TCP connections to the port 5000 in inbound rules of firewall. I have also tried changing the ports. I have tried switching off the firewall completely but nothing seem to work. What could be the problem??? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your config should be fine. What error do you get, 4xx or 5xx? Can you try to explicitly host on said IP address instead of 0.0.0.0? Also, are you 100% sure the service is up and running and you are allowed to reach said PC from your own on another port (such as ssh)?

Comment: Ok so there could be some issue in the router's firewall policies And when I switched both devices to other router it worked fine.

Comment: So it seems to be a network issue indeed. Good thing you figured it out.